# Given a Field and a Record, how to obtain the value of that Field within that Record?

Tags: lift, lift-record

I have something like:

```scala
val jobs = Job.where(...).fetch()
val fieldsToDisplay = Seq(Job.status, Job._id, ...)
val header = fieldsToDisplay map { _.name }
val tbl = jobs map { j => fieldsToDisplay map { _.getValueIn(j) } }
renderTable(header, tbl)
```

...and it's that hypothetical `getValueIn` I'm looking for.

I've been unable to find anything, but perhaps more experienced Lift'ers know a trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Field has a name that is unique within the Record

```
jobs map { j => 
  fieldsToDisplay map { f => 
    j.fieldByName(f.name) 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Weird... must have completely overlooked `fieldByName`.